# Como usar grupo de checkbox para fazer busca com php e mysql

Tags: php, mysql, select, checkbox, get

Estou desenvolvendo um site de imoveis com uma busca, onde um dos filtros é o bairro. Atualmente ele é um dropbox, mas gostaria de trocar por grupo de checkbox para poder selecionar mais de 1 bairro por vez, como posso fazer isso?

Pensei em alguma forma de enviar as informações mais ou menos assim: (&bairros=centro,tatuape)

A busca é feita com o $_GET.

```
Form:
<form id="buscalancamento" name="nomebuscalancamento" method="get" action="/incorporadora/terrenos">
<select type="text" name="bairro">
<option>Todos</option>
<option>Centro</option>
<option>Tatuape</option>
</select>
<button type="submit"">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

E a consulta:

```
$bairro = $_GET['bairro'];
//FILTRO BAIRRO
if (isset($bairro)) {
    if($bairro=='Todos'){
        $wbairro='';
    }else{
        $wbairro=' AND bairro LIKE "'.$bairro.'" ';
    }
}else{$wbairro='';}
$query=("SELECT *, FROM #__ter_terrenos WHERE id > 0".$wbairro);
$db -> setQuery($query);
```

Eu não sei como enviar todos os chebkox com os valores juntos, nem fazer a consulta com esses dados enviados

Comment: Já tentou trocar o LIKE por IN? Já que os bairros são gerados por um select e não informado pelo usuário não teria a necessidade de utilizar o LIKE...

Comment: Sobre utilizar os valores enviados, eles serão enviados como array por post ou get caso seja post só utilizar um var_dump($_POST['nome_do_campo']); para verificar o que está chegando, depois utilize um IMPLODE para juntar a array.

Comment: Vc pode também converter o dropbox em multiple onde o usuário poderá selecionar vários itens. É só adicionar `multiple`: `<select multiple>`

Comment: @LucasGauna vou testar com o IN, mas como faço para enviar no get todos os checkbox selecionados juntos?

Comment: @sam pensei nisso, mas o cliente queria como checkbox mesmo, ao clicar em selecionar bairro ele aparece um grupo de checkbox

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo, praticamente você terá que fazer isso : "'".implode(" ',' ", $array)."'";

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo no lugar da array você usa o seu conjunto de checkbox, vale lembrar que o nome deles deve estar correto, que seria name="checkbox[]". Da uma testada e retorna o resultado aqui. O mais importante é você dar um var_dump no campo da checkbox e verificar se esta chegando como array ou não.

Comment: ve se entendi, no lugar do select, vou colocar algo assim: <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Centro"> <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="Tatuape">? se for, fiz aí ele apareceu no get: checkbox%5B%5D=Centro&checkbox%5B%5D=Tatuape

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo Estarei realizando alguns testes por favor espere um minuto, estarei colocando como resposta

Comment: @LeandroMarzullo, você utiliza Jquery?

Comment: @LucasGauna, posso usar

Answer (score 1):

(desculpa meu português mas não sou nativo)

Você precisa usar vários checkbox com o mesmo nome, para que no arquivo php os dados possam se receber como array. Logo você faz um implode nos dados e pode usar IN de Mysql. Exemplo:

**No HTML**:

```
<form id="buscalancamento" name="nomebuscalancamento" method="get" action="revision_mg.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="Todos">
<input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="bairro1">
<input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="bairro2">
<input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="bairro3">
<input type="checkbox" name="bairro[]" value="bairro4">
<button type="submit">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

**No PHP**:

```
<?php
$wbairro = "";
//FILTRO BAIRRO
if (isset($_GET['bairro'])) {//melhor fazer validação aqui e logo alocar a variável
    $bairro = $_GET['bairro'];
    if(in_array("Todos", $bairro)){
        $wbairro='';
    }else{
        $wbairro = " AND bairro IN(";
        $wbairro .= "'" . implode("','", $bairro) . "'";
        $wbairro .= ")";
        }
}else{$wbairro='';}


$query=("SELECT *, FROM #__ter_terrenos WHERE id > 0".$wbairro);
$db -> setQuery($query);
?>
```

Como voce precisa uma url mais limpa, eu fiz o siguente, mas o código eh um pouco mais complexo. Uso javaScript para adaptar a URL: então quando você faz click sob o check ele manda os dados para uma função de javascript, e ela vai criando um array com os valores que você seleciona, se você apaga um check então ela quita o valor do array. Quando você da click em buscar, então novamente se chama uma função de javascript que pega os valores do array, aloca ao input hidden e envia por a url:

**HTML:**

```
<form id="buscalancamento" name="nomebuscalancamento" method="get" action="revision_mg.php">
<input type="checkbox" id="Todos" onChange="alocar('Todos')">
<input type="checkbox" id="barrio1" onChange="alocar('barrio1')">
<input type="checkbox" id="barrio2" onChange="alocar('barrio2')">
<input type="checkbox" id="barrio3" onChange="alocar('barrio3')">
<input type="checkbox" id="barrio4" onChange="alocar('barrio4')">
<input type="hidden" id="bairros" name="bairros" value="">
<button type="button" onClick="send()">Buscar</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    var bar = Array();
    var barrios = document.getElementById("bairros");
function alocar(valor){//Pega o valor do check

    if(document.getElementById(valor).checked == true){//Se ta ligado agrega o valor
        bar.push(valor);        
    }else{//Se desliga apaga o valor do array
        let index = bar.indexOf(valor);
    if (index !== -1) bar.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

function send(){
    var juntar = "";
    let cant = bar.length;
    //Criar um string com o dados do array
    for(i = 0; i < cant - 1; i++){
        juntar = juntar + bar[i] + "_";
    }

    //Deixa o ultimo elemento fora para evitar um _ demais ao final do String
    juntar = juntar + bar[cant -1];

    barrios.value = juntar;
    document.getElementById("buscalancamento").submit();
}
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
$wbairro = "";
//FILTRO BAIRRO
if (isset($_GET['bairros'])) {
    $bairro = $_GET['bairros'];
    if(strpos($bairro, "Todos") !== false){
        $wbairro='';
    }else{
              $wbairro = " AND bairro IN(";
        $wbairro .= "'" . str_replace("_", "','", $bairro) . "'";
              $wbairro .= ")";

        }
}else{$wbairro='';}

$query=("SELECT *, FROM #__ter_terrenos WHERE id > 0".$wbairro);
$db -> setQuery($query);
```

Espero possa te ajudar

Comment: funcionou, mas no url ficou bairros%5B%5D=bairro1&bairros%5B%5D=bairro2, tem como ficar algo assim: bairros=bairro1,bairro2 ou qualquer outro caracter no lugar da virgula, para ficar repetindo o bairros%5B%5D= e ficar um link muito grande

Comment: O method tem que ser GET? porque poderla usar method POST, assim os dados vão no corpo do form e não na url

Comment: tem que ser get, porque o cliente quer poder aplicar o filtro e comparilhar o link com o filtro que ele fez

Comment: Consegui o que voce precisa, vou atualizar minah resposta

Comment: O código que fiquei de enviar faz a mesma coisa do que o do @JoseMelendez, considero a resposta dele correta, mas estarei fornecendo o meu código de qualquer jeito.

Answer (score 0):

Minha resposta usa o princípio parecido com a do @JoseMelendez, mas com uma programação um pouco diferente e, na minha opinião, mais simplificada.

Crie um `input` oculto após os `checkbox`, colocando a classe `.bairro` nos `checkbox`, exceto na do "Todos", e o `name="bairro"` apenas no `input` oculto, conforme abaixo:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="centro" class="bairro"> centro
<input type="checkbox" value="tatuape" class="bairro"> tatuape
<input type="checkbox" value="Todos"> todos
<input type="hidden" name="bairro">
```

Crie um evento `onsubmit` pelo JavaScript que irá inserir no `input` oculto o `value` a ser enviado, nas seguintes condições:

- Se nenhum `checkbox` for marcado, será considerado "Todos";
- se o `checkbox` "Todos" for marcado, ele terá prioridade, mesmo tendo marcado outros.

**JavaScript:**

```
var form = document.forms[0];
form.onsubmit = function(){

   var bairros = document.querySelectorAll(".bairro:not([value='Todos']):checked");
   var bairro = '';
   for(var x=0; x<bairros.length; x++){
      bairro += bairros[x].value+',';
   }

   bairro = bairro.substring(0, bairro.lastIndexOf(","));
   form.bairro.value = document.querySelector("[value='Todos']:checked") || !bairro ? "Todos" : bairro;

}
```

No PHP você fará um `explode` convertendo a variável `$bairro` em array e fazendo um `foreach` irá construir a consulta `IN()`:

```
$bairro = $_GET['bairro'];
//FILTRO BAIRRO
if (isset($bairro)) {
    if($bairro=='Todos'){
        $wbairro='';
    }else{
      $bairro = explode(",", $bairro );
      foreach($bairro as $item){
         $consulta .= '"'.$item.'",';
      }
      $wbairro = ' AND bairro IN('.rtrim($consulta, ",").')';
    }
}else{$wbairro='';}
$query=("SELECT *, FROM #__ter_terrenos WHERE id > 0".$wbairro);
$db -> setQuery($query);
```

O resultado do `foreach` irá montar o `IN()` com os valores desta forma:

```
AND bairro IN("centro","tatuape")
```

A função `IN()` irá retornar apenas os registros que tiverem o termo nos parâmetros.

O resultado do GET na URL será algo como:

```
/incorporadora/terrenos?bairro=centro%2Ctatuape
```

Onde o código `%2C` representa uma vírgula.

Answer (score 0):

Segue código como comentei que iria estar fazendo.
Será gerada uma URL assim = "bairros=bairro1%2Cbairro2%2Cbairro3"
**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="GET" id="pesquisa">
    <input type="hidden" name="bairros" id="bairros" value="">
    <input type="checkbox" value="bairro1" data-name="bairro" checked>bairro1
    <input type="checkbox" value="bairro2" data-name="bairro">bairro2
    <input type="checkbox" value="bairro3" data-name="bairro">bairro3

    <button type="submit">enviar</button>
</form>
```

**JS (Jquery):**

```
$(document).on('submit','#pesquisa',function(e){
    var bairros = '';

    $('input[type="checkbox"][data-name="bairro"]:checked').each(function( index ) {
        bairros = bairros + $(this).val()+',';
    });
    bairros = bairros.substring(0,bairros.length - 1);
    $('#bairros').val(bairros);
});
```